# Почему hover только для первой строки?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

```css
.text {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: BloggerSans;
}

.text:hover {
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<a class="text">Hello.<br>fdsjfhsdfhjjds.<br> sdfdsfsdfsdf.<br> sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf.</a>
```

Почему при наведении на текст переносит влево только Hello? Как сделать что бы все переносило.

Comment: потому что это одна строка, разделенная тегом <br>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.text {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: BloggerSans;
  display:block;
}

.text:hover {
  margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<a class="text">Hello.<br>fdsjfhsdfhjjds.<br> sdfdsfsdfsdf.<br> sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf.</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Выбирай:

```
.text { display: block; }
```

```
.text { display: inline-block; }
```

Но вообще, это ужасная идея.